# same view model different errormessage asp .net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel, data-annotations

I have a contact viewmodel which I use to strongly type my partial view "Contact". In one of my form I got to use the same Contact partial view for two areas ex. Customer as well as Vendor.

Is there a way to give two different error message ex: **Please enter "Customer" Name and Please enter "Vendor" Name** using the same view model?

Now it shows **two** general error messages **"Please enter name"** (Which is what is specified for the required attribute error message).

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

TIA.

Regards,

Raja

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best pattern here is to create a second view model, don't try to simply save on code if they really serve two different purposes.

A second option is your model implements IValidateableObject interface and adds this custom message as required

A third option is in your controller if you detect the field isn't there simply use ModelState.AddModelErrors. You could make it not a required field and check in your controller if its present or query modelstate's errors  to see if its there, clear it out and re-add it with the updated text.

Comment: Thanks Adam. I am now at a stage where I cannot make any major change. I already started to work on the third option but before I went too far just wanted to confirm if there is another way of doing it.